# Is there a fix for this LaTeX rendering artefact?

Tags: pdftex, rendering

While reading this PhD thesis

[David Farrell, Weak Compactness in Banach Spaces: James' Theorem and Convex Analysis.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342916385_Weak_Compactness_in_Banach_Spaces_James%27_Theorem_and_Convex_Analysis)

On page 9 I noticed rendering anomalies, reproduced below.

[image: Double modulus rendering artefact]

On closer inspection I noticed the double modulus symbol is not rendered as two single lines but rather each apparent single line is made out of five smaller subsections.

The effect is visible, below, even when using the Adobe pdf viewer. I can notice the modulus symbol is made of smaller lines which overlap and in doing so it produces artefacts.

[image: Line rendering artefacts]

The artefacts from Google's rendering engine appear to be explained by the fact not all of those smaller subsections align properly, but in Adobe, even though they align properly they still don't anti-alias smoothly, you can see bumps where the lines overlap.

This result somewhat less than what I expect from LaTeX.

Is there a way to eliminate those effects?

Comment: I have no access to the pdf but in my experience in 99% of the cases this has inevitably to do with the viewer. Does the effect vanish when zooming in?

Comment: The question includes a link to the thesis which has a link to the pdf so you do have access to it. The picture below is a rendering using the Adobe renderer. The artefacts are still detectable and it doesn't look like a fault with the pdf rederer it looks like a fault in the pdf file passed to it by the LaTeX compiler. As for "does the effect vanish when zoomed in". Can you see the zoomed in version above? No, it doesn't.

Comment: Oh, right, I must have made something wrong the first time I've tried it. But in my viewers (okular on SuSe and both Chrome viewer & pdfXchange on Win10) they look perfect.

Comment: I am tempted to try it to confirm but it involves a lot of software installation. Can you zoom in on the modulus symbols and verify it isn't there?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GLK59By

Comment: Yes indeed campa. I concur. That does look ideal!

Comment: The question still remains though: I cannot force people to use my renderer of choice to view .pdf files generated by LaTeX so the problem will still exist, for example, for people using Google Chrome to view LaTeX documents. What I really want is for LaTeX Not to generate five separate lines for the modulus symbol.

Comment: stretchy delimiters are always specified by the font and made of multiple stacked glyphs in the particular case of straight lines you could consider drawing rules but the general case needs to enlarge ( or { so these are constructed.

Comment: There is [at least one attempt](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) at solving this issue with the stretchy delimiters; this involves designing individual symbols at difference sizes and an algorithm to figure out which size to use... so requires _both_ additional font support and TeX shenanigans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a flaw in the Google PDF viewer. Getting proper translation of positioning text elements to pixels is not something that can do naïvely, even at high resolutions. The logic in [DVItype.web](https://ctan.org/pkg/dvitype?lang=en) goes to great lengths to manage this and as far as I know, every dvi post processor borrows Knuth's logic towards that end.

But writing to PDF, you end up swapping one virtual coordinate system (TeX's sp = 1/65536 of a TeX pt = 1/72.27in measured as integer values) for another (PDF's point = 1/72in measured as floating point values) and you're at the mercy of the PDF viewer to maintain the translation of PDF coordinates to pixels. Anecdotally, every viewer does this correctly *except* for Google's viewer which is actually transforming the PDF to HTML and doesn't deal with pixels at all which is why things end up looking so bad.

Growing delimiters is something that happens at a low level in TeX's typesetting engine in cooperation with special aspects of the font in question (if you ever print a font table of, e.g., cmex10 you'll notice that the delimiter pieces position themselves oddly in the table) and while finding some way to replace vertical bars with rules might solve this particular issue, other big delimiters would still suffer so I don't think that there's any work around to the limitations of the Google PDF-HTML viewer.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Having said that though, the main reason for using that image is to show the modulus symbol is made of five smaller sections. In the zoom image near the bottom of the original post the rendering of those five subsections is still visible, even in the Adobe desktop .pdf viewer app. Wouldn't it be better, and fix the issue, to encode the modulus symbol as one single line section, rather than five smaller section joined end-to-end?

Comment: @GeorginaDavenport It would take rewriting TeX itself and you'd have to deal with how you also typeset other large delimiters such as (), [] and {} (this last one is why there are five segments).

Comment: Sounds like a "no" then. It is a shame though. Unlike braces, modulus symbols are, after all, just straight lines. It may be a small issue, but it is still a disappointment since it comes from what is frequently lauded as the final word in formal technical document beautification. However small it is, it's a shame to find such a flaw.